# PostgreSQL two dimensional array intersection

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, intersection

is it possible with postgres tools to intersect two-dimensional arrays?

For instance I have:

```
id               arr
1    {{1,2}, {3,4}, {4,5}, {4,7}}
2    {{4,2}, {7,4}, {8,5}, {9,7}}
```

...

And I want to get all records that have `{4,5}` in theirs array, record `id=1` here.
If I do something like:

```
select * from table where arr && '{4,5}'
```

I'll get both of those example records. It finds all records where are 4 and 5 are anywhere in the array - as if it was looking in fully extracted arrays, like `{1,2,3,4,4,5,4,7}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought of using functions from the extension [intarray](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/intarray.html), but:

> Many of these operations are only sensible for one-dimensional arrays.
> Although they will accept input arrays of more dimensions, the data is
> treated **as though it were a linear array** in storage order.

My other ideas:

#### Quick and dirty

```
WITH x(id, arr) AS (VALUES
    (1, '{{1,2}, {3,4}, {4,5}, {4,7}}'::int[])
   ,(2, '{{4,2}, {7,4}, {8,5}, {9,7}}')
   )
SELECT * 
FROM   x
WHERE  arr::text LIKE '%{4,5}%';
```

The simple trick is to transform the array to its text representation and check with `LIKE`.

#### With array-functions

```
WITH x(id, arr) AS (
    VALUES
     (1, '{{1,2}, {3,4}, {4,5}, {4,7}}'::int[])
    ,(2, '{{4,2}, {7,4}, {8,5}, {9,7}}')
    )
    ,y AS (
    SELECT id, arr, generate_subscripts(arr, 1) AS i
    FROM   x
)
SELECT id, arr
FROM   y
WHERE  arr[i:i] = '{{4,5}}'::int[];
```

Or, the same in different notation, building on your example:

```
SELECT id, arr
FROM  (
    SELECT id, arr, generate_subscripts(arr, 1) AS i
    FROM   tbl
    ) x
WHERE  arr[i:i] = '{{4,5}}'::int[];
```

This generates the array subscripts for the first dimension. With the help of this set-returning function we check each array-slice. Note the double brackets on the right hand side of the expression to create a two-dimensional array that matches.

If `{4,5}` can be in `arr` multiple times, add `GROUP BY` or a `DISTINCT` clause to avoid duplicate rows.

Comment: yes, trick with string types is what i was thinking too, but i was sure, it is not a good solution and there is something better. thanks a lot